# “ValueError: Input 0 is incompatible with layer cropping2d_1: expected ndim=4, found ndim=3”

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, opencv, keras

I'm appeding single color channel image to an array

```
image = cv2.cvtColor(cv2.imread(path), cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
tmp = image[:,:,1].reshape(160, 320, 1)
images.append(tmp)
```

But, during start of the Sequential model, I'm getting

> ValueError: Input 0 is incompatible with layer cropping2d_1: expected
>   ndim=4, found ndim=3

How does `Cropping2D` work for single color channel image??

Model starts like:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Lambda(lambda x: x/255.0 - 0.5, input_shape=(160, 320, 1)))
model.add(Cropping2D(cropping=((50, 20), (0, 0))))
```

Answer (score 0):

According [to the documentation](https://faroit.github.io/keras-docs/1.2.2/layers/convolutional/#cropping2d), the expected input tensor shape to the `Cropping2D` layer is:

```
(samples, depth, first_axis_to_crop, second_axis_to_crop)
```

The first dimension is your batch size, or number of examples.  The second dimension is the number of channels (1 in your case), and finally the third and fourth parameters are the number of rows and columns you want to crop your image by.

You haven't provided your complete setup, so we don't know what your expected batch size is.  Let's assume it's `None` for now meaning that you will decide what the batch size is later.

The culprit is most likely your conversion of the image to grayscale:

```
model.add(Lambda(lambda x: x/255.0 - 0.5, input_shape=(160, 320, 1)))
```

You'll need to change this to suit the dimensions of the `Cropping2D` layer.  Specifically, there is no `input_shape` parameter [as far as I can see from the documentation](https://keras.io/layers/core/#lambda).  In addition, you need to shift the dimensions around so that the channel appears first, followed by the rows and columns, so switch around the parameters in `reshape`:

```
image = cv2.cvtColor(cv2.imread(path), cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
tmp = image[:,:,1].reshape(1, 160, 320)
images.append(tmp)
```

Going back to `input_shape`, you should actually let the `input_shape` be inferred from the previous layer, so simply omit it assuming you've set up the layers correctly:

```
model.add(Lambda(lambda x: x/255.0 - 0.5))
```

Comment: Lambda is the first layer

Comment: @dodawamo That's right.  The expected input shape into `Lambda` should be one that is compatible to the next layer.  You're not doing that.  You have to switch around the channels so that it can be fed into the `Cropping2D` layer after.